# How to uninstall homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I installed homebrew today without really knowing what I was doing, and now my scikit-learn package is broken.  I want to undo everything that I did by uninstalling homebrew, and tried following the tips here:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/FAQ

However, I think homebrew installed into /usr/bin/local, and not /usr/bin/, so I'm not sure I can use the instructions in the link.

When I initially installed homebrew (`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`), I got the following messages:

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
==> The following directories will be made group writable:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/local/share/man/man3
/usr/local/share/man/man5
/usr/local/share/man/man7
```

Can I just delete the files in

```
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
```

I'm terrified of screwing something up in the uninstallation process. 
Incidentally, would uninstalling homebrew even restore my system to what it was before?  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-uninstall-Homebrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the homebrew FAQ:

https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew

It specifies a script you can run to do it.  You should run that script.  As of right now, the script says something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Just copy and paste the lines below (all at once, it won't work line by line!)
# MAKE SURE YOU ARE HAPPY WITH WHAT IT DOES FIRST! THERE IS NO WARRANTY!
 
function abort {
  echo "$1"
  exit 1
}
 
set -e
 
/usr/bin/which -s git || abort "brew install git first!"
test -d /usr/local/.git || abort "brew update first!"
 
cd `brew --prefix`
git checkout master
git ls-files -z | pbcopy
rm -rf Cellar
bin/brew prune
pbpaste | xargs -0 rm
rm -r Library/Homebrew Library/Aliases Library/Formula Library/Contributions 
test -d Library/LinkedKegs && rm -r Library/LinkedKegs
rmdir -p bin Library share/man/man1 2> /dev/null
rm -rf .git
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew
rm -rf /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

Comment: Does that work if homebrew is installed in /usr/local/bin, and not /usr/local?

Comment: (oops, misread your question). Homebrew installs in several places under `/usr/local` and elsewhere; only commands like `brew` go in `/usr/local/bin`. This script tries to clean up the entire Homebrew installation. Your output from Homebrew installation looks normal to me.

Comment: Ok, I ran the script, and I got the following:  Does this look right?

Clockwork-Orange:~ ****$ ./script.sh

Already on 'master'

Pruned 0 dead formula

Pruned 15 symbolic links from /usr/local

Comment: Many of the steps in the script don't have output -- that looks fine to me.  Are you still having problems with scikit?  If so, open a thread and I'll find it and help you.

Comment: No more problems with scikit-learn!  Although I'm not 100% sure it's because I uninstalled homebrew.  I actually ended up reinstalling scikit-learn by re-cloning the github repository, etc. Hopefully everything will be okay from here on out.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 5):

**This worked for me**

Official brew [uninstalling](https://github.com/Homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew) steps:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

But `/usr/bin/ruby` is just symlink in order to find your ruby you need to type

```
which ruby
```

Which will give you `/snap/bin/ruby`

So then just use this :

```
/snap/bin/ruby  -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Comment: From the script output:
`Warning: The Ruby Homebrew uninstaller is now deprecated and has been rewritten in
Bash. Please migrate to the following command:
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"`

Answer (score 3):

The is the updated recommended way

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

You may gout output like this:

```
The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted:
/opt/homebrew/Frameworks/
/opt/homebrew/bin/
/opt/homebrew/etc/
/opt/homebrew/include/
/opt/homebrew/lib/
/opt/homebrew/opt/
/opt/homebrew/sbin/
/opt/homebrew/share/
/opt/homebrew/var/
You may wish to remove them yourself.
```

To remove run:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

Clean as a whistle!

Comment: This should be the answer these days.  The above equivalent curls don't work any more.

Answer (score 1):

Just run this code in terminal:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the cli:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Comment: better to use the system ruby