# Problems after installing nodejs

Tags: node.js, centos

I was trying to install nodejs using homebrew. After the installation process finished with error my os seems to be broken. I can not run any commands. not even the basic commans lik `cd` and `ls`. I am getting following error.

[image]

I reverted changes in bashrc file. Has someone faced similar problem ? what could be the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out homebrew broke something in my case. As soon as I unistalled homebrew things were back to normal.

I used this link to unistall.

> [How to uninstall homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251665/how-to-uninstall-homebrew)