# I can't uninstall brew on MacOS Apple Silicon

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-silicon, timemachine

Like it is mentioned here https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew I typed
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"` but it doesn't seem to work...

When I type afterwards `which brew` it returns `/usr/local/bin/brew`

and when I type again `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"`

It displays :

> /bin/bash: line 236: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew: No such file or directory
> Failed to locate Homebrew!

So I don't know what to do to uninstall brew.

My ultimate goal is to not getting this error when I try to install a brew package :

> Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default
> prefix (/usr/local)! Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew
> using one of the "Alternative Installs" from:
> https://docs.brew.sh/Installation You can migrate your previously
> installed formula list with:   brew bundle dump

I now have a Mac with Apple Silicon but I used to have a Intel Mac.

EDIT 1 : I took a quick look at the `uninstall.sh` script here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh

It seems that my problem is induced by my os installation because I did it from an Intel-based MacOS time machine backup. The problem is the `uninstall.sh` script is programed to uninstall homebrew according to the current os. So this script can only uninstall the ARM homebrew that I need and can't uninstall the Intel homebrew I try to get rid of...

Maybe I should try to just change the line of code that detect I have a ARM CPU to make the script think I have a Intel-based Mac but I don't know if it could bring chaos in my computer...

I'm surprised there's not a lot of answers about this problem since I don't think I'm the only one to have switched from Intel-based Mac to ARM-based Mac with Time Machine.

EDIT 2 : I tried to uninstall Homebrew with a command of my own `arch -x86_64 ./uninstall_brew.sh` (I have no idea if it's not DANGEROUS) but I don't know if it worked well...

Here is the output of the command :

```
user@MacBook-Pro % arch -x86_64 ./uninstall_brew.sh
Warning: This script will remove:
/Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/
/usr/local/Caskroom/
/usr/local/Cellar/
/usr/local/bin/brew -> /usr/local/bin/brew
Are you sure you want to uninstall Homebrew? This will remove your installed packages! [y/N] y
==> Removing Homebrew installation...
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
/usr/local/share/info/dir: Permission denied
Warning: Failed to delete /usr/local/Caskroom
rm: /usr/local/Caskroom: Permission denied
Warning: Failed to delete /usr/local/Cellar
rm: /usr/local/Cellar: Permission denied
==> Removing empty directories...
Password:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/find /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/opt /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/Frameworks -name .DS_Store -delete
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/find /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/opt /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share /usr/local/var /usr/local/Caskroom /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/Frameworks -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} ;
==> Homebrew uninstalled!
The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted:
/usr/local/.com.apple.installer.keep
/usr/local/Frameworks/
/usr/local/Homebrew/
/usr/local/bin/
/usr/local/etc/
/usr/local/git/
/usr/local/include/
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/local/man/
/usr/local/opt/
/usr/local/remotedesktop/
/usr/local/sbin/
/usr/local/share/
/usr/local/var/
You may wish to remove them yourself.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251665/how-to-uninstall-homebrew)

Comment: The OP has a similar problem but the link given in the answer he validated is a 404 error. The given solution tells the answer I search is in the FAQ but I've looked carefully and I didn't find it.

Comment: Do you have permission on those folders? Can you delete them manually?

Comment: I have admin rights but I'm a bit afraid to use them in case it could be dangerous for the computer.

Comment: I mean to use admin rights with the uninstall.sh script in case it could uninstall important files.

Comment: You cannot uninstall without using your admin rights

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this question!  I went through the same process as you and was feeling lost on how to solve it.  It's fixed now!

Answer (score 11):

Try running: `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"`

Found the answer here: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/3437

Comment: For M1 I needed to tweak it like this: `PATH=/opt/homebrew:$PATH arch -arm64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"`

Comment: @Starsky's tweak worked for me. Just a thing to note, might have to go into the `/opt/homebrew` folder and delete what the script wasn't able to delete. Had some folders left after the script ran

Answer (score 4):

I encounter similar issue on my M1 MBP, and I found that changing the uninstall path in the script may work.

First, I download a local copy of the uninstalling script

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh
```

Then run the script locally and set the path to `/user/local`(which is the default path of homebrew on intel Mac)

```
/bin/bash uninstall.sh --path=/usr/local
```

but it completed with 2 warnings I'm not sure what they are

```
Warning: Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo rmdir /usr/local
Warning: Homebrew partially uninstalled (but there were steps that failed)!
To finish uninstalling rerun this script with `sudo`.
The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted:
/usr/local/Cellar/
/usr/local/Frameworks/
/usr/local/Homebrew/
/usr/local/bin/
/usr/local/etc/
/usr/local/include/
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/local/opt/
/usr/local/sbin/
/usr/local/share/
/usr/local/texlive/
/usr/local/var/
You may wish to remove them yourself.
```

Either way, I delete those files manually.

(This is my first time to answer something on stack overflow. Hope this help!)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.
The solution is just to remove your git configuration from your mac.

Command: `rm -rf ~/.gitconfig`

After executing the command try to install brew. Command: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

After installing homebrew install the brew git
command: `brew install git` then configure your GitHub profile.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and easy fix for that would be just use `arch -x86_64` infront of your uninstall command it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that `uninstall.sh`, there's a spot where `homebrew_prefix_default` gets set according to the processor type, and there's usage info that says:

```
-p, --path=PATH  Sets Homebrew prefix. Defaults to ${homebrew_prefix_default}.
```

So it sure looks like you can override the default location by passing the `--path=...` option with the path that you want, namely the one that the script would've chosen for an Intel machine, i.e `/usr/local`.